# How to resize and remove unneccessary space in the datgrid in mudblazor when height is fixed

Tags: c#, css, datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

I am using muddatagrid and I have set the height for the datagrid which changes dynamically based on screen size it dispays the scrollbar when the rowsperpage exceed the height. But the problem arises when the the number of records is less than the height or  rowsperpage , there will be excessive space between the pager content and the records in bottom of the datagrid .

For example, if there is less than 10 records to display, then there will be a space in the bottom of the datagrid, between actual records and pager content(I have added paging).This happens in last page as well when there are multiple pages. In this case, I want to set the height to remaining pages and let it to be auto height in last page where records are lower than the mentioned height. How can I achieve this.

This is my code

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Filterable="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" RowsPerPage="@rowsperpage"  Context="context" FixedHeader="true" Height="@((Service.Height-100).ToString() + "px")">
        @*  @ref="dataGrid" Height="@((currentpage==(int)(Elements.Count()/rowsperpage))&&((Elements.Count()%rowsperpage) ==0) ? ("100px"):"auto")"
          ColumnResizeMode="@((currentpage==(int)(Elements.Count()/rowsperpage))&&((Elements.Count()%rowsperpage) ==0) ? ResizeMode.None : ResizeMode.Column)" @bind-CurrentPage="@currentpage">*@
   <Columns>
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
</Columns>
 <NoRecordsContent>
  <MudText>No matching records found</MudText>
```

I have added mudblazor snippet for this issue.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQIEHaSwUQhyioT

I want to adjust the height if the record's height is lowerer than the fixed height of datagrid.

Comment: Please add your code into the question directly. Linking to an off-site location is not sufficient. See [mre] for more info.

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

There is indeed a simpler solution to this problem. Simply set the `max-height` in class `mud-table-container`.

```
<style>
    .mud-table-container{
        max-height: 500px
    }
</style>
```

[snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQeYdFvHZOUyaBk)

**Old Answer**

There's surely a better solution to this, but atleast this one works for me.

You can define a method to "recalculate" the Height. For me the hard part was to define an event when it is called since it appears that the DataGrid does not have a "CurrentPage changed event". So I call the method each time a row is rendered:

```
<Columns>
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
        <TemplateColumn Title="Molar mass">
            <CellTemplate>
                @(RecalculateHeight())
                @context.Item.Molar
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

The RerenderGrid Method simply checks if the `CurrentPage` is the last one and if necessary call `StateHasChanged`

```
private string RerenderGrid()
{
    if(Elements.Count() == 0 || dataGrid.CurrentPage == (Elements.Count() / rowsperpage)) 
    {
        if(dataGrid.Height == "500px")
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    else if(dataGrid.Height == string.Empty)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

The grid then sets again its Height for which it uses the GetHeight Method

```
private string GetHeight(){
    if(Elements.Count() == 0 || dataGrid.CurrentPage == (Elements.Count() / rowsperpage)) 
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else 
    {
        return "500px";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call it

```
 <MudDataGrid 
    @ref="dataGrid" 
    Items="@Elements" 
    Filterable="true" 
    FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" 
    RowsPerPage="@rowsperpage"  
    Context="context" 
    FixedHeader="true" 
    Height="@GetHeight()"
>
```

[MudSnippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QuceEduoxCJteuCv)