# How to adjust the size and remove excessive space in the datgrid in mudblazor when height is set dynamically

Tags: c#, css, datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

I am using muddatagrid and I have set the height for the datagrid which changes dynamically based on screen size it dispays the scrollbar when the rowsperpage exceed the height. But the problem arises when the the number of records is less than the height or rowsperpage , there will be excessive space between the pager content and the records in bottom of the datagrid .

For example, if there is less than 10 records to display, then there will be a space in the bottom of the datagrid, between actual records and pager content(I have added paging).This happens in last page as well when there are multiple pages. In this case, I want to set the height to remaining pages and let it to be auto height in last page where records are lower than the mentioned height. How can I achieve this.

This is my code

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Filterable="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" RowsPerPage="@rowsperpage"  Context="context" FixedHeader="true" Height="@((Service.Height-100).ToString() + "px")">
    @*  @ref="dataGrid" Height="@((currentpage==(int)(Elements.Count()/rowsperpage))&&((Elements.Count()%rowsperpage) ==0) ? ("100px"):"auto")"
      ColumnResizeMode="@((currentpage==(int)(Elements.Count()/rowsperpage))&&((Elements.Count()%rowsperpage) ==0) ? ResizeMode.None : ResizeMode.Column)" @bind-CurrentPage="@currentpage">*@
<Columns>
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" />
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position" />
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
</Columns>
<NoRecordsContent>
<MudText>No matching records found</MudText>
```

I have added mudblazor snippet for this issue.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQIEHaSwUQhyioT

I want to adjust the height if the record's height is lowerer than the fixed height of datagrid.

[image]

This is what I am getting now as output but what output I want is

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq5HK.png]

When the height of all the data exceed the height of datagrid it will create a scrollbar, but when the data height is lower than the set height(dynamically set) it will create unnecessary . I want to fix that get output like the above image.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize and remove unneccessary space in the datgrid in mudblazor when height is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78099781/how-to-resize-and-remove-unneccessary-space-in-the-datgrid-in-mudblazor-when-hei)

Comment: @Uerschel This works fine if rowsperpage is low , if I select 50 or 100 it will exceed the height so scrollbar should appear, but  instead as per your condition it will resize so it will exceed the height . I want that condition to be checked as well

Comment: Ah I see. But the question is the same, isn't it? It may be better to edit your other question so it gets reopened.

Comment: I updated my answer with a much simpler approach. I think it is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Uerschel I am setting the height dynamically like this  Height="@((Service.Height-100).ToString() + "px")" .how to change this to max-height.

Comment: You can't change it to max height. When RowsPerPage changes you would have to set the value based on various factor like I tried with my first solution. 'Height' will only be called on a rerender, so changing the value alone isn't sufficent. You would need an event to rerender the datagrid.

And in my opinion it's best to remove the Height property and add max-height for the 'mud-table-container' class internally.

Comment: @Uerschel I tried it. I can set max-height through style if height is a static value  but as it changes dynamically I cant set it though style I want to find another way to set max-height dynamically.